# How to get started developing for Pocket PC 2003 SE?

Tags: java, java-me, windows-mobile

I recently obtained a Symbol PDA which runs Pocket PC 2003 SE. I would like to develop apps for it, but I don't know where to get started. I have researched the options and tried to develop in C# which didn't end up working. I also heard that Java ME can be used with Windows Mobile. This would be ideal because I have had most of my coding experience with Java. I can't seem to figure out how to get any of the solutions to work though. I would like help getting started in either language.

Comment: I think there are project templates in Visual Studio (not 2010 and later though) for developing for mobile devices, this is PPC, WM5, WM6 etc, so it should working using the PPC template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOr clarification, there was no such thing as "Windows Mobile 4".  The Windows Mobile naming started with 5.0, proir to that it was Pocket PC 2003SE, which is probably what you have.  It's likely based on CE 4.2, hence the number you've got.

Development options are:

- [eMbedded Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24809) (C++)
- Visual Studio 2003 Professional or better (CF 1.0, C# or VB.NET)
- Visual Studio 2005 Standard or better (CF 1.0 or 2.0, C# or VB.NET)
- Visual Studio 2008 Professional or better (CF 2.0 or 3.5, C# or VB.NET)
- [NSBasic](http://www.nsbasic.com)
- CrEme (as pointed out by @Miquel)

There may be more, but this covers the common ones.  I've used all but the last and deployed production apps using all but the last two. As for CrEme - I've never used it, nor known anyone that did. YMMV.

Comment: Yes, your right, it is Pocket PC 2003 SE.

Comment: I still am a little confused about how to deploy eMbedded Visual C++ applications to the actual device, not the emulator.

Comment: Change the target device from the emulator to the PocketPC 2003 device - should be a drop-down in the menubar somewhere.  I can't give you a screen shot as I don't have eVC installed on anything any longer.

Answer (score 2):

If programming in Java:

You could use the [CrEme](http://www.nsicom.com/Default.aspx?tabid=138) Java virtual machine to code directly in Java. UI's are in AWT, but you could also use SWT, which I think might give you a better result.

A @jp2code's request, here's a tutorial I used with some examples and a bit of code to get you started: [A small cap of SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-small-cup-of-swt/pocket-PC.html)
Have fun!!

Comment: Hi Miquel. Would you mind editing your post to include a few links to code examples? I'm not saying I will be going to Java for my developments, but I'd like to see what types of things are possible for Mobile devices using Java.

Comment: Sure, edited. Please note it was quite a while ago that I developed on this platform!